# Creating a buffer with less than 1 centimeter using a polyline

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, buffer

Using ArcPy, I aim to create the smallest possible buffer, ideally just 1 millimeter. I have a code, but it only functions properly when I set the buffer parameters to a value of 2 centimeters or more.

```
import arcpy

poligonos = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

#polygon to line codigo completo
arcpy.PolygonToLine_management(poligonos, "ftl", "IDENTIFY_NEIGHBORS")

#transforma o ftl em layer
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("ftl", "featuretoline_lyr")

#selecione todas as linhas que tem dois vizinhos
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("featuretoline_lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", '"LEFT_FID" <> -1 AND "RIGHT_FID" <> -1')

#crie uma camada temporaria com as linhas selecionadas
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("featuretoline_lyr", "featuretoline_lyr2")

#buffer de 10 milimetros nas linhas selecionadas, right, round, all
arcpy.Buffer_analysis("featuretoline_lyr2", "buffer", "2 Centimeters", "RIGHT", "ROUND", "ALL")

#crie uma camada temporaria com os poligonos
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(poligonos, "poligonos_lyr")

#erase dos poligonos com o buffer
arcpy.Erase_analysis("poligonos_lyr", "buffer", "erase")


#delete das camadas temporarias
arcpy.Delete_management("ftl")
arcpy.Delete_management("featuretoline_lyr")
arcpy.Delete_management("featuretoline_lyr2")
arcpy.Delete_management("buffer")
arcpy.Delete_management("poligonos_lyr")
arcpy.Delete_management("erase")
```

My main goal is to separate snapped polygons erasing the connections between them.

Comment: What does 'only functions properly' mean? Is there an error message? Does your computer catch fire? Blue screen of death? Do you get output but it's not what you expected? milimeters is a valid unit for buffer or if you don't like that set your buffer to 0.001 meters (note the American spelling of metres).

Comment: Sorry i didn't explained.
ArcGIS Pro outputs me an empty shapefile. 

Yeah! It's a valid unit but i don't know why it dont works.

Comment: Tomorrow i'll run my tool again and i'll SS the output.

Comment: A one millimeter for a buffer is asking for trouble if your `SpatialReference` doesn't have tenth-millimeter coordinate precision. You might be dealing with vertex collapse due to integerization rounding. The XYTolerance might be playing a role as well.

Comment: Have you tried changing/setting the [tolerance settings](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/environment-settings/xy-tolerance.htm) "The x,y tolerance refers to the minimum distance between coordinates before they are considered equal."

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it!